# Shell command/script to delete files whose names are in a text file

Tags: file, shell, scripting, delete-file

I have a list of files in a .txt file (say list.txt). I want to delete the files in that list. I haven't done scripting before. Could some give the shell script/command I can use. I have bash shell.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
while read -r filename; do
  rm "$filename"
done <list.txt
```

is slow.

```
rm $(<list.txt)
```

will fail if there are too many arguments.

I think it should work:

```
xargs -a list.txt -d'\n' rm
```

Comment: Although `rm $(<list.txt)` is faster, +1 for mentioning the limitation it has on the number of arguments.

Comment: $ for i in *; do echo $i; done > ~/a
$ rm frd.xml
$ while read f; do rm $f; done < ~/a
The above code works given by a colleague. This looks very similar to your answer. Thank you!

Comment: does this remove files in subdirs too?

Comment: _xargs: illegal option -- a_

Comment: xargs option worked for me...of course....i had to keep 1 filename per row, with no spaces in between, no quotes at the beginning and end....a completely sanitized plain text string works....and I had more than 900,000 files to be deleted

Comment: What is the difference between `$(<list.txt)` and `$(cat list.txt)`? Is one preferable to the other?

Answer (score 12):

Try this command:

```
rm -f $(<file)
```

Comment: Your question says you have a list of file names in `list.txt`.  Apparently, you don't.  :-)

Comment: Either that or you need to give the full path to lists.txt

Comment: or `gio trash $(<list.txt)` to send them to the trash :)

Answer (score 5):

If the file names have spaces in them, none of the other answers will work; they'll treat each word as a separate file name.  Assuming the list of files is in `list.txt`, this will always work:

```
while read name; do
  rm "$name"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Good point. Problem is the OP doesn't have a file called `list.txt` so this is causing him problems for some reason ;-)

Comment: Right.  See my comment on Tim Pote's answer.

Answer (score 3):

For fast execution on macOS, where `xargs` custom delimiter `d` is not possible:

```
<list.txt tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work and leaves you room to do other things as you loop through.

Edit: Don't do this, see here: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

<strike>for file in $(cat list.txt); do rm $file; done</strike>

Comment: its giving me an error. rm: cannot remove 'cat': No such file or directory. rm: cannot remove 'list.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Changed format slightly. Did you use back ticks before? Note @TimPote answer might be better?

Comment: thanks for the answer. There seems to be something wrong with my bash environment. But got no one to check my workstation at my office currently and I cant post that problem here. So, Il just have to wait till Monday(next working day) till someone takes a look at it.

Comment: @AdamLiss: Oh wow, I had no idea. Thanks for enlightening! Note your first link was more interesting, especially as it relates to the exact example I posted, repeated here: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @yamen: Thanks for the repost.  I couldn't decide which link would be more helpful.  In general, you can replace `$(cat foo)` with `$(<foo)` to avoid spawning an extra process (and, if you're me, typos as well).

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a solution to this today and ended up using a modified solution from some answers and some utility functions I have.

```
// This is in my .bash_profile

# Find
ffe () { /usr/bin/find . -name '*'"$@" ; } # ffe: Find file whose name ends with a given string

# Delete Gradle Logs
function delete_gradle_logs() {
   (cd ~/.gradle; ffe .out.log | xargs -I@ rm@)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can try:

```sh
printf "%s\n" $(<list.txt) | xargs -I@ rm @
```

In my case, my .txt file contained a list of items of the kind `*.ext` and worked fine.