# Shell script to delete whose files names are not in a text file

Tags: shell, file, scripting

I have a txt file which contains list of file names

Example:

```
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpeg
...
```

In a folder this files should protect from delete process and other files should delete.

So i want oppposite logic of this question: [Shell command/script to delete files whose names are in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149203/shell-command-script-to-delete-files-whose-names-are-in-a-text-file)

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extglob` and Bash extended pattern matching `!(pattern-list)`:

> !(pattern-list)
>   Matches anything except one of the given patterns
>   where a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a |.
>
> extglob
>   If set, the extended pattern matching features described above are enabled.

So for example:

```
$ ls
10.jpg  11.jpg  12.jpeg  13.jpg  14.jpg  15.jpg  16.jpg  a.txt
$ shopt -s extglob
$ shopt | grep extglob
extglob         on
$ cat a.txt
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpeg
$ tr '\n' '|' < a.txt
10.jpg|11.jpg|12.jpeg|
$ ls !(`tr '\n' '|' < a.txt`)
13.jpg  14.jpg  15.jpg  16.jpg  a.txt
```

The deleted files are `13.jpg  14.jpg  15.jpg  16.jpg  a.txt` according to the example.

So with `extglob` and `!(pattern-list)`, we can obtain the files which are excluded based on the file content.
Additionally, if you want to exclude the entries starting with `.`, then you could switch on the `dotglob` option with `shopt -s dotglob`.

Comment: Cool feature; I didn't know about this. Seems to be the cleanest and most efficient solution. As a bonus, it will also work when the text file lists patterns itself as discussed in my answer. (Hopefully, this is the desired behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way that will work with bash GLOBIGNORE:

```
$ cat file2
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
$ ls *.jpg
10.jpg  11.jpg  12.jpg  13.jpg
$ echo $GLOBIGNORE

$ GLOBIGNORE=$(tr '\n' ':' <file2 )
$ echo $GLOBIGNORE
10.jpg:11.jpg:12.jpg:

$ ls *.jpg
13.jpg
```

As it is obvious, globing ignores whatever (file, pattern, etc) is included in the GLOBIGNORE bash variable.

This is why the last `ls` reports only file `13.jpg` since files 10,11 and 12.jpg are ignored.

As a result using `rm *.jpg` will remove only `13.jpg` in my system:

```
$ rm -iv *.jpg
rm: remove regular empty file '13.jpg'? y
removed '13.jpg'
```

When you are done, you can just set GLOBIGNORE to null:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=
```

Worths to be mentioned, that in GLOBIGNORE you can also apply glob patterns instead of single filenames, like `*.jpg` or `my*.mp3` , etc

**Alternative :**
We can use programming techniques (grep, awk, etc) to compare the file names present in ignorefile and the files under current directory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{f[$0];next}(!($0 in f))' file2 <(find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf '%f\n')
13.jpg

$ rm -iv "$(awk 'NR==FNR{f[$0];next}(!($0 in f))' file2 <(find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf '%f\n'))"
rm: remove regular empty file '13.jpg'? y
removed '13.jpg'
```

Note: This also makes use of bash process substitution, and will break if filenames include new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to George Vasiliou's answer would be to read the file with the names of the files to keep using the Bash builtin `mapfile` and then check for each of the files to be deleted whether it is in that list.

```
#! /bin/bash -eu

mapfile -t keepthose <keepme.txt
declare -a deletethose

for f in "$@"
do
    keep=0
    for not in "${keepthose[@]}"
    do
        [ "${not}" = "${f}" ] && keep=1 || :
    done
    [ ${keep} -gt 0 ] || deletethose+=("${f}")
done

# Remove the 'echo' if you really want to delete files.
echo rm -f "${deletethose[@]}"
```

The `-t` option causes `mapfile` to trim the trailing newline character from the lines it reads from the file.  No other white-space will be trimmed, though.  This might be what you want if your file names actually contain white-space but it could also cause subtle surprises if somebody accidentally puts a space before or after the name of an important file they want to keep.

Note that I'm first building a list of the files that should be deleted and then delete them all at once rather than deleting each file individually.  This saves some sub-process invocations.

The lookup in the list, as coded above, has linear complexity which gives the overall script quadratic complexity (precisely, *N* × *M* where *N* is the number of command-line arguments and *M* the number of entries in the `keepme.txt` file). If you only have a few dozen files, this should be fine. Unfortunately, I don't know of a better way to check for set membership in Bash. (We cannot use the file names as keys in an associative array because they might not be proper identifiers.) If you are concerned with performance for many files, using a more powerful language like Python might be worth consideration.

I would also like to mention that the above example simply compares strings. It will not realize that `important.txt` and `./important.txt` are the same file and hence delete the file. It would be more robust to convert the file name to a canonical path using `readlink -f` before comparing it.

Furthermore, your users might want to be able to put globing patterns (like `important.*` into the list of files to keep. If you want to handle those, extra logic would be required.

Overall, specifying what files to *not* delete seems a little dangerous as the error is on the bad side.

Answer (score 1):

Provided there's no spaces or special escaped chars in the file names, either of these (or variations of these) would work:

1. `rm -v $(stat -c %n * | sort excluded_file_list | uniq -u)`
2. `stat -c %n * | grep -vf excluded_file_list | xargs  rm -v`